# Subfigure arrangment with no caption with IEEE format

Tags: tables, subfloats, subcaption, ieeeconf

I have a little problem. I am trying to arrange to subfigures side by side (i.e. a graph and its legend) using the IEEE article format and I cannot remove the subcaption.

I was using package subfigure at first but I don't want to have the subcaption underneath the figures (i.e. (a), (b) ).

By searching on the internet, I've found out that package *caption* could do the job, but seems to have some compatibility issues with the IEEE class file.

Therefore I had to create a table and put the figures in the table. However, now the legend is not centered. Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.135]{fig_graph} &  \includegraphics[scale=0.115]{Legend} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption text.}
\label{fig_graph}
\end{figure}
```

**Question:**

How is possible to put two figures side by side with no subcaption and without using the caption package (and no graphical editors if possible)?

**Using *subcaption*** didn't helped. I forgot to mention that I am using *IEEEConf* not IEEEtran.

I modified the code as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.135]{fig_graph}
\phantomcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill

\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.115]{Legend}
\phantomcaption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption text.}
\label{fig_graph
\end{figure}
```

And now MikTex 2.9 complains that subcaption and subfigure cannot be used together.

If I remove subfigure, the compiler gets VERY angry on another subfigure I have

> Missing number, treated as zero.\letl.214 \label{fig_matrices}}).
>   and a lot more complaining about missing numbers and illegal units like pt (I guess beacuse subfigure is needed)

The packages I am importing are:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\overrideIEEEmargins

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{cite}
```

The error I get if I use caption is:

> Command \c@subfigure already defined.

If I use caption by giving:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]
```

I get many errors:

> Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.
>
> Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@pti@ns was complete.
>
> Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.
>
> Undefined control sequence.
>   \@fileswith@pti@ns ...served@b \reserved@a ,\@nil,}\fi \reserved@al.37 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

And a lot more most of them about not finding things or finding things and think that are undefined.

I was kind of aware that people may get just a warning for caption, but what's wrong with this?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In what sense the caption is not centered?

Comment: Hi egreg, thank you for your welcome! :) The second figure (Legend) is not vertically centered with respect to the first figure (fig_graph). The subcaption (i.e. (a) ) should not be there at all

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a warning, it just says a macro is redefined that's all. `subfigure` package is old and obsolete. You should never use it for anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `caption` or `subcaption`, if you don't want any special label for the graphics.

```
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %<- For dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images

\title{The research}
\author{The researcher}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\kant[1-4]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=4cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
}\qquad
\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm]{example-image-b}%
}
\caption{The proper caption}
\label{figab}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I imposed height and width to the images in order to emulate your real situation, where the two pictures have different heights.

With `\raisebox{-.5\height}` we shift vertically the reference point (usually at the bottom) for each picture, so they come out automatically center aligned. With `\qquad` I add some separation; leave it out (changing it into a `%`) if you don't want any space.

[image]

Comment: @Occh'iPapara I fixed my code (there still was the unused `subcaption` package); it works unchanged for `IEEEconf`, only the output is different.

Comment: the fontsize for the Fig. breaks and would be refused by officials

Comment: @ItsmeJulian What font size are you referring to?

Comment: Fig.1.: the proper caption. by standard is smaller then the text, see answer percusse

Comment: @ItsmeJulian I do *no* change to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you think there is a compatibility issue. There is a certain redefinition of commands but the result is not incompatible. You just get a warning. So you can use `\phantomcaption` command. Also you need to train it a little. I typically use the following settings

```
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %<- For dummy text
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images

% Remove the trailing whitespace from citations
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

% Training subcaption package to comply with
% IEEE standards. We can ignore the warning
% generated by caption.sty which is due to 
% the redefinition of \@makecaption
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{periodspace}{.\quad}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,labelsep=periodspace,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[sub]{font=footnotesize,singlelinecheck=true}

\title{The research}
\author{The researcher}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1]
\end{abstract}

\kant[1-4]

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\phantomcaption{}%
\label{subfiga}%
\end{subfigure}\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}%
\phantomcaption{}%
\label{subfigb}%
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The proper caption}
\label{figab}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]