# Error in compiling \includepdf

Tags: bibliographies, pdfpages, include

My latex file is something like this:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    ...
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{my_bib}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{my_file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that while compiling, the last page of the main document i.e. the references appear with the last page of `my_file.pdf`. What could be the possible solution ?

Comment: A `\newpage` before `includepdf`?

Comment: No, it didn't help, the same problem

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** I think I have reproduced your error now, after using the `IEEEtran` document class as you said, because when adding more `lipsum`, text started to float into the included pdf file. Fixed it by adding a `\cleardoublepage`.   I noticed `newpage` alone is not enough here.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \cite{ref1}
    \lipsum
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{my_bib}
    \cleardoublepage
    \includepdf[pages=-]{my_file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose its the problem with my document class, I changed my documentclass and its working without any warning. But I have been using \documentclass{IEEEtran} and ignored one warning: usage of caption package is not recommended. I guess the whole problem is because of this warning ?

Comment: Ah, maybe for the next time it's handy to include a MWE of which you know it doesn't work, so including the documentclass and everthing we need with which we can reproduce the error. You can test this out yourself, in a new file or something. But anyway, when I use `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` my MWE still compiles fine... it doesn't on your side? Seems that it has to do with some package, maybe? the caption package doesn't cause any problems on my side.

Comment: Yes, Now I figured it out, it was because of this particular doumentclass. I used the this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133037/subfigure-arrangment-with-no-caption-with-ieee-format and problem is solved.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I solved a different problem then? Ah well, the more solutions the better. I'm glad it is solved anyway!