# Subfigure breaks caption size

Tags: captions, subfloats, ieeetran

On the IEEE paper layout i use subfigure/subfloats two place two figures side-side. While the a) b) tags are ok the main caption (also for other figures) increase to textsize (shown on the left col). How to keep things uniform small.

[image]

The code is long: main parts are:

```
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{figure}[!b]
\subfloat[geo-tagged resources]{\label{rsspl}\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth,valign=c]{figures/rssplf.png}}
\subfloat[radial LV circuit]{\label{circuitth}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=c]{figures/circuitth.png}}
\caption{Co..eer.}
\label{rsspl}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Note that IEEE requires the [caption=false] option of subfig so as to not load the caption package.  Comsoc requires [font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf] (see page 10 of the manual).

Answer (score 1):

Best approach:
`\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`

---

Other: add 
`\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,singlelinecheck=false}`. Another approach with  begin-subfigure [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133041/102334)